# JQL query search in Jira

Tags: jira, jql

I am not able to search this item in Jira due to specified errors below.

```
Query: project = 'foo' and description ~ 'testing:'test''

Result: Error in the JQL Query: Expecting either 'OR' or 'AND' but got 'test'. (line 1, character 7

4)
```

I know that, the double quotes will resolve the problem but it is not working in some of the condition like below.

```
Query: project = 'foo' AND description ~ "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Result: Error in the JQL Query: Expecting either 'OR' or 'AND' but got 'NoneType'. (line 1, character 106)
```

Could someone help me with a condition that can be used to search as a string no matter what is given inside?

Note: Search statement cannot be alternated in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have the quotes wrong, try like this with alternating quotes ('/")

```
project = 'foo' AND description ~ 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str'
```

and for the first query

```
project = 'foo' and description ~ "testing:'test'"
```